# Can alternative sites now be added to off-topic/migration?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration, cross-validated, stack-overflow

I see this was asked a while ago in [Offer Additional Options for "Off Topic" Flag](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/offer-additional-options-for-off-topic-flag) - however this was answered with a clear "no" because we were a beta site at the time.

Recently I saw this question: [Work breakdown of data project](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24017/work-breakdown-of-data-project) and thought it was more suited to Workplace as it is primarily about communication between a project planner and a researcher - the latter happens to be in a data scientist role.

Could we now add a few more sites than the current "should be on meta". Obvious choices include:

- Stack Overflow, for coding bugs or advice using core language features not related to data science (perhaps the question asker just happens to be working on a data science problem in that language).
- Workplace, for work relation and behaviour issues that just happen to involve data scientists (*maybe* - we have a sample of one here that triggered my Meta question)
- Cross Validation - maybe, although we'd need to be clear with ourselves what the boundaries are when something stops being a Data Science issue and starts to be suitable for that site. I am suggesting it regardless though, because having that migration target may give us data samples on what the community thought on this long-running issue.

Maybe other sites would also be suitable, based on potential migrations others have seen on the site? For instance I suggested Cognitive Science Stack Exchange recently for a question, although that is a beta site so not possible.

Comment: I'm up for it, just don't know how one changes the options. I don't see any option for me to do it.

Comment: @SeanOwen We can take help from the folks at the Teacher Lounge chat.  I'd wait a week more for answers before jumping into the task :)

Comment: Is there any update to this? I stumbled over multiple questions where I would like to cast a closing vote with reference to other pages (e.g. multiple pure coding questions).

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be helpful. Some thoughts on the potential list.

- [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) seems to be doing fairly well, and would seem to be a good target for migration. But as a beta site is not an option for migration?  I recently moderator flagged on for migration, I think it got done.
- Stack Overflow - This one can be tricky, because while the question may be programming related, they can often be poor enough quality to not be on topic at SO either.
- Suggesting Cross Validation as a target is thorny. The discussion around the need to *be clear with ourselves what the boundaries are* is likely to bring out some trolls.

Comment: Note that some of the main ML package contributors now use github for tracking problems and route to SO for practical problems. (tensorflow / lightgbm) Might be usefull to take that into account.